# What is the best way of defining different user roles in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

say i have 2 user classes apart from common attributes like username, email..etc, they have some different attributes. Is it better to have one User Schema and differentiate them by roles or Is it better to create separate Schema for both of the classes?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice shows us that it's always better to have one User Schema and just differentiate them by roles in such a cases.